# Parsing a website with Jsoup that dynamically loads as the user scrolls

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm working on a project that displays song names and a link to that song by parsing a website using Jsoup. The only problem is, I can only get the first 10 elements that I want from that website because as you scroll down, the website generates more elements. The specific website I'm trying to parse is a music site called [TrappedIO](http://trapped.io/). You'll notice when viewing the website that when you scroll down, more song names and images appear. When I use inspect element in chrome, I see that as I scroll, it generates more of elements I'm trying to parse.

The CSS Path of what I'm parsing: #content > div.container > div > div:nth-child(index of element)

The problem is when I get this website with Jsoup using this method,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

HTML returned from Jsoup: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/E0z711yi)

Only the first 10 elements I want to parse are returned, along with all the other HTML.
To be more specific, I'm parsing using Jsoup in an AsyncTask, then populating a ListView with the parsed data.

Any ideas? Any suggestions on how to load everything at once? Any response is very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite simple, to get the next set of 10, just hit the following

```
http://trapped.io/?page=2
```

To generalize, just feed proper page number in `page=PAGE_NUMBER` query parameter, you can get a set of 10 elements in that page.

#### Edit:

*Just a side note, there might be legal issue in scraping sites. I hope you've double checked its legally ok to do scraping on their site.*

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed! I'll make sure to check with the website devs on their irc, thanks for letting me know.